# Material Popover Scrollable content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popover

I use React and Material-UI. I use huge Popover with the Tooltip behaviour. The goal is to display data when the user hover some links. It's working well but i have a problem about scrolling.

I want to be able to scroll INSIDE the popover when the Mouse is inside it. The default behaviour is to let the user scroll the entire page instead of focus on the popover.

I have set a [CodeSansBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-dawn-l7c31?file=/src/App.js) to show you.

Comment: I don't see anything in the sandbox link you've provided, except codesanbox's default code

Comment: You're right, I have corrected that ^^' Too tired to notice i didn't save the thing :P

Comment: don't worry... relax.. every problem has a solution... :)